# how to rectify the error "exit status 1 exponent has no digits" in arduino programming?

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

i need help in debugging an arduino program that i just typed. the error shown is:-
1.exit status 1 exponent has no digits ( found on line "char INT_ENABLE = 0*2E" ).
the intention of the program is to set off a buzzer and turn off a relay switch when inactivity is sensed through adxl345 and do the opposite when activity is sensed. 
i am providing my program code below.  have a check and help me in rectifying this problem and any other problem that you may find with my program.

```css
#include <SPI.h>
int cs = 10;
int intr = 2;
int buzzer = 4;
int relay = 5;
int su = 1;
int intr1
pinmode (buzzer,OUTPUT);
pinmode (relay,OUTPUT);
char POWER_CLT = 0*2D
char DATA_FORMAT = 0*31
char DATAX0 = 0*32
char DATAX1 = 0*33
char DATAY0 = 0*34
char DATAY1 = 0*35
char DATAZ0 = 0*36
char DATAZ1 = 0*37
char THRESH_ACT = 0*24
char THRESH_INACT = 0*38
char TIME_INACT = 0*26
char INT_ENABLE = 0*2E
char INT_MAP = 0*2F
char ACT_INACT_CTL = 0*27
char INT_SOURCE = 0*30

char values[10];
char output[20];
int x, y, z;
char inactivityevent = 0;
void setup()
{
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(cs,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(cs, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(digitalpintointerrupt(intr),interruptHandler,RISING); 
  writeRegister(DATA_FORMAT,0*01);
  writeRegister(POWER_CTL,0*08);
  writeRegister(INT_MAP,0*F7 && 0*EF);
  writeRegister(THRESH_INACT,1);
  writeRegister(TIME_INACT,0);
  writeRegister(ACT_INACT_CTL,0*0F);
  writeRegister(INT_ENABLE,0*08);
  readRegister(INT_SOURCE,1,VALUES);
} 

void interrupHandler()
{
  read register (INT_SOURCE,1,values);
}

void loop() 
{
 intr1=digitalread(intr);  
 if ( intr1==high)
  { 
   read register(DATAX0,6,values);
   x = ((int)values[1]<<8|(int)values[0]);
   y = ((int)values[3]<<8|(int)values[2]);
   z = ((int)values[5]<<8|(int)values[4]);
   if ( x<=15 && x>=-15 && y<=10 && y>=-10 && z>=75 && z<=90)
    {
     digitalwrite(buzzer,HIGH);
     digitalwrite(relay,LOW);
    }
   else
    {
     for (int i=0;i<=90;i++)
      {
       delay (2000);
       if (intr == LOW)
        { break(); }
       if (i==90)
        digitalwrite(relay,LOW);       
      }
    }
  while (su=1)
   {  
    if (intr==LOW)
     {
      digitalwrite(buzzer,LOW);
      digitalwrite(relay,HIGH);
      break(); 
     }
   }       
 }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax for hexadecimal constants is not correct - it should be 0x, not 0* (the X is not a multiplication sign!). You've got tons of other syntax errors, too. C (and most other programming languages) is very picky about syntax, and you can't deviate from the language specification (unlike, say, English).

Comment: thanks a million for that correction. i studied this myself and obviously i got it wrong. i used one of the program found at this site as a base program and tried to build one from there.the link is provided below. it would be really helpful if you can help me rectify most of the syntax errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701400/programming-arduino-with-adxl345-to-raise-interrupt-on-inactivity?rq=1

Comment: You typed in the code there but with many mistakes. I recommend typing it in again but being very precise about uppercase/lowercase, symbols and "punctuation" characters.

Comment: thnku for you concern.i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the `0*nn` values in the program, replace them with `0xnn`.  Make sure each line finishes with a semicolon (e.g., lines 7, 10-24).  On line 40, check the expression containing `&&` because that's a "logical" operator and you look like you want a "bitwise" operator there, so change `&&` to `&`.  In line 45, I think you need `VALUES` to be lower case, because the name of the variable you are trying to fill in is lower case.
There are a couple of places you say `read register` but I think you need to use `readRegister` for those.
Check line 78, which has the while loop checking the value of `su`.  I think you should have `while (su == 1)` here instead of just one `=`.  The single `=` is setting the value, but I think you want to check the value instead, hence you need `==`.  I do note that there's nothing in the program to change `su` from `1`, so it will go on forever until the `intr` happens.

Comment: regarding logical operator "&&" ,as i told in the previous comment,i took a program from this site as a base program to develop mine and in it, they have used this. i believe the idea is to send the data to both the addresses. thank you for the great help. i am providing a link to the base program that i talked about earlier. perhaps you could understand more than me and help me understand that part of the program better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701400/programming-arduino-with-adxl345-to-raise-interrupt-on-inactivity?rq=1

Comment: I looked at that program, and it has the same form that you quoted.  However I think that person didn't have it correct, because `0xF7 && 0xEF` is just the same as saying `1`.  However my correction suggested above won't work either I think.  I don't know enough about the specific device but you may get some good info about INT_MAP [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/240).

Comment: thank you for your reference and your help. i was able to rectify all the errors in my program. currently i am waiting for my components to test my program.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question as it's the top Google result for the error message, so in case anyone ends up here, here's what's actually happening. This line is the problem:

```
char INT_ENABLE = 0*2E
```

this was supposed to have been

```
char INT_ENABLE = 0x2E;
```

where `0x` indicates that `2E` is a hexadecimal number. However the compiler reads the original code as `zero times 2E`, and interprets `2E` as an attempt to write a floating-point number that is missing it's exponent.

For anyone who has not seen this before, you can write a number like 2 million as `2e6`, which means `2 followed by 6 zeros` or `2 times 10 to the power of 6`. The first number is known as the Mantissa, the second is the Exponent. Hence the error message `exponent has no digits`.

In my case the problem was that the number 1 looks the same as a lower-case L, and my nephew had mistyped/misread a variable as `1ed` instead of `led`.

[image]